# How can DRF serialize model form for the end point?

Tags: django, serialization, django-forms, django-rest-framework, modelform

I am wonder if there any serializer for the model form, like [django-remote-forms](https://github.com/WiserTogether/django-remote-forms).

I noticed there is HTMLFormRenderer class for rendering, but I don't know how to use this in the view. Does it work like django-remote-forms?